# Object.assign(), functional approaches and memory usage

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I do this in Javascript (ES6):

```
let originalState = [
    { id : 1, name : "One"},
    { id : 2, name : "Two"},
    { id : 3, name : "Three"}
]

let newState = Object.assign({}, ...originalState)
```

Will the objects in "newState" reference the objects from "orignalState" in memory, or will they be cloned, taking up new memory?

Comment: lol, Tusar, sooo fast!

Comment: I believe it's `Object.assign({}, ...originalState)`

Comment: Hope this helps. http://www.es6fiddle.net/inn9ebby/

Comment: Yeah thats right Tushar, thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the objects in "newState" reference the objects from "orignalState" in memory, or will they be cloned, taking up new memory?

There won't be multiple new objects. There is only one object that is stored in the `newState` variable, it's the one you've created with the object literal:

```
let newState = Object.assign({}, ...originalState)
//                           ^^ here
```

The properties in `newState` will be created by standard assignment - they will exist separately from the ones of the `originalState` objects but contain the same value.